# Delivering a mix for shortmovie Lo Ro or Lt Rt

Tags: production-mixing

I've been requested to mix the audio for a short movie I worked in as sound recordist. Nothing particularly challenging, but considering it will be on the web and probably in some festival I run in this issue:

What format do I have to deliver into? LR would be the more obvious on the web, but if it is going to be in some theatre for a festival?

My setup is stereo, can I just add a 3<sup>rd</sup> monitor and trying to make a 3.0 mix and encode it in Lt Rt? Is there any way to encode Lt Rt with some plugin available or other apps like compressor?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to deliver a 3.0 mix (possibly as a 5.1 with silence on surrounds and LFE) for the theaters and a 2.0 for web/broadcast.

LtRt doesn't seem to have any advantages today (if you want to deliver a 3.0 mix, use a 5.1 ac3 or aac encoded stream that most players will be able to downmix to 2.0 if needed.

Comment: thanks, I use commonly Apple Compressor that seems to be very useful for ac3 encoding. it gives the possibility to set the downmix, I have not tested it yet deeply but among his main set it doesn't offer the lt rt, it gives[! this feature only as downmix option.

 [ac3 setting windows on compressor preset][1]][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMF2b.jpg

Comment: LtRt is not part of ac3 encoding. Even the LtRt downmix metadata seems useless in today's landscape. I would use 3.0 with LoRo downmix.

Comment: I see you have similar answers on gearslutz https://www.gearslutz.com/board/post-production-forum/1214519-how-deliver-when-there-no-specification.html